# How to use Quazip with Qt 5.6, Qt Creator on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, qt, quazip

Sorry that I am not experienced in this kind of stuff, but I have been searching the internet for a while to find out how to use Quazip with Qt 5.6 on Win 10. I would greatly appreciate a list of steps on how to build Quazip and use it in Qt Creator.

So far, I tried downloading Quazip, and including the pri file in my .pro file

```
include(quazip-0.7.2/quazip.pri)
```

Then I replaced every instance of:

```
#include "zlib.h"
```

and

```
#include <zlib.h>
```

to

```
#include <QtZlib/zlib.h>
```

After I do this, I have many compiler warnings along with a few errors.

My errors are :

```
QuaZIODevice::staticMetaObject': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
QuaGzipFile::staticMetaObject': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
QuaZipFile::staticMetaObject': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

And all 15 of my warnings contain:

```
inconsistent dll linkage
```

I greatly appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from the documentation:

> By default, QuaZIP compiles as a DLL/SO, but you have other options:
>
> - Just copy appropriate source files to your project and use them, but you need to define QUAZIP_STATIC before including any QuaZIP headers (best done as a compiler option). This will save you from possible side effects of importing/exporting QuaZIP symbols.

This seems to be what you're doing, so you should probably add `DEFINES += QUAZIP_STATIC` to your .pro file.